# How to parse dynamic JSON with Flutter?

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I do not understand how to parse a JSON file I get from firebase.

This is the format of the JSON file

```
{
  "water" : {
    "-MnRJkFC3--ZOTmpF1xN" : {
      "milliliters" : 0.14,
      "time" : "16:26:25"
    },
    "-MnRJkZRwZYEInHfSKIY" : {
      "milliliters" : 48.83,
      "time" : "16:26:25"
    },
    "-MnRJksES18hY765rxxq" : {
      "milliliters" : 41.44,
      "time" : "16:26:25"
    },
    "-MnRJlDn6o4RmiGRJS-E" : {
      "milliliters" : 11.37,
      "time" : "16:26:25"
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I am reading the JSON file

```
Future loadSalesData() async {
  final String jsonString = await getJsonFromFirebase();
  final dynamic jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
  for (Map<String, dynamic> i in jsonResponse)
    chartData.add(SalesData.fromJson(i));
  }
```

The getJsonFromFirebase() looks like this:

```
Future<String> getJsonFromFirebase() async {
  String url =
      "https://emailpassword. . .seio.com/water.json";
  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  return response.body;
}
```

When you click on the link it send you to the JSON file which looks like this

```
{
    "-Mnbk2ye2P8bfpaQvNaU": {
        "milliliters": 0.0,
        "time": "18:07:00"
    },
    "-Mnbk6wd-wJze8P0JknK": {
        "milliliters": 0.12,
        "time": "18:07:00"
    },
    "-Mnbk7Ek629vgBu-MiLg": {
        "milliliters": 44.91,
        "time": "18:07:00"
    },
    "-Mnbk7bPuzqwsz9d5nm6": {
        "milliliters": 5.43,
        "time": "18:07:00"
    },
    "-Mnbk7v7MADi7YzEbeFI": {
        "milliliters": 24.54,
        "time": "18:07:00"
    },
    "-Mnbk8DGfqswckdsA1qP": {
        "milliliters": 47.58,
        "time": "18:07:00"
    },
    "-Mnbk8Xw2kJPxLrqCl6h": {
        "milliliters": 13.98,
        "time": "18:07:00"
    }
}
```

I get the Error

> _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

Comment: What does `getJsonFromFirebase` look like?

Comment: Hi Frank, this is how the getJsonFromFirebase looks like                                                                                            Future<String> getJsonFromFirebase() async {
    String url =
        "https://emailpass. . . .firebaseio.com/water.json";
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    return response.body;
  }                                                                                                                                        
   The link sends you to JSON file on my realtime database

Comment: When you click the link the JSON file looks like this                                                           
{"-Mnbk2ye2P8bfpaQvNaU":{"milliliters":0.0,"time":"18:07:00"},"-Mnbk6wd-wJze8P0JknK":{"milliliters":0.12,"time":"18:07:00"},"-Mnbk7Ek629vgBu-MiLg":{"milliliters":44.91,"time":"18:07:00"},"-Mnbk7bPuzqwsz9d5nm6":{"milliliters":5.43,"time":"18:07:00"},"-Mnbk7v7MADi7YzEbeFI":{"milliliters":24.54,"time":"18:07:00"},"-Mnbk8DGfqswckdsA1qP":{"milliliters":47.58,"time":"18:07:00"},"-Mnbk8Xw2kJPxLrqCl6h":{"milliliters":13.98,"time":"18:07:00"}}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems `flutter` does not understand that `jsonResponse` is an `iterable` because you defined it as `dynamic`.

Adjust the definition to tell flutter it is a map:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
```

Comment: This is just plain wrong. All it does is change the error from a runtime error (as above) to a compile time error, as now the compiler _knows_ the type is not an `Iterable`. Have you actually tried this out @Nairobi or @Canada2000?

Comment: Yeah, I did try it and I had to just alter the For Loop and it was able to fetch the JSON file from firebase

Comment: @msbit I also alterd my code as you indicated and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

With the shape of the JSON you are receiving, [`json.decode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-convert/JsonCodec/decode.html) will return a [`Map<String, dynamic>`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/Map-class.html) (more specifically an instance of the `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>` specialisation). This type doesn't implement [`Iterable`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/Iterable-class.html), so you can't iterate over it directly with the `for-in` construct, and this is the exact error you are getting, at run time.

Depending on what you need to construct your `SalesData` instance, you have two options:

- iterate over the [`entries`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/Map/entries.html) property, if you need the `key` of each item (`"-Mnbk2ye2P8bfpaQvNaU"`, `"-Mnbk6wd-wJze8P0JknK"` etc), otherwise
- iterate over the [`values`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-core/Map/values.html) property, if you don't

##### Entries

###### Iteration:

```
for (MapEntry<String, dynamic> i in jsonResponse.entries) {
  chartData.add(SalesData.fromJson(i));
}
```

###### `SalesData.fromJson`:

```
SalesData.fromJson(MapEntry<String, dynamic> data) {
  id = data.key;
  milliliters = data.value['milliliters'];
  time = data.value['time'];
}
```

##### Values

###### Iteration:

```
for (Map<String, dynamic> i in jsonResponse.values) {
  chartData.add(SalesData.fromJson(i));
}
```

###### `SalesData.fromJson`:

```
SalesData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
  milliliters = data['milliliters'];
  time = data['time'];
}
```

##### Type Inference

Additionally, regardless of how you decide to iterate over the `Map` instance, you can clean up the code a little taking advantage of Dart's [type inference](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#type-inference), so (presuming you are iterating over the entries) `loadSalesData` could become:

```
Future loadSalesData() async {
  final jsonString = await getJsonFromFirebase();
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);

  for (final i in jsonResponse.entries) {
    chartData.add(SalesData.fromJson(i));
  }
}
```

and `getJsonFromFirebase` could become:

```
Future<String> getJsonFromFirebase() async {
  final url = "http://localhost:8080/data.json";
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  return response.body;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was in detail and It helped alot